# /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, debian, raspbian

Currently I'm on a Raspbian OS that installed to virtual machine on Windows with Vmware. I have this error that tells me I'm missing ld-linux-armhf.so.3.

What can I do? How can I install ld-linux-armhf.so.3? Any ideas?

```sh
$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release: 10 Codename: buster
```

```sh
$ uname -m
x86_64
```

Comment: What do you do, in order to see such error? Did you install an external package? In that case: check if there is one version for your raspbian version, or get the source package and build yourself the package.To me, it seems something wrong on who created the package (cross-compiling?)

Comment: Note: the file is from the standard library, so a "fix" could break completely your raspbian.

Comment: I am trying to start my python executable file. That is work fine on raspberry pi but when I try to execute on new Raspbian (which I install on a pc) I get this error.

Comment: It is the reason you will find a lot of package (per distribution sometime also per distribution version). Or you create carefully binaries, so that they are compatible with many libraries [check building and linking options, also for every dependency, often not possible], or just build an executable for every mayor version of distributions.